# When server rendering, you must wrap your application in an <SSRProvider> to ensure consistent ids are generated between the client and server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have this warning in console... im working with NextJs and Next UI.

I've tried everything, aslo i have searched here but nothing works.

Comment: Have you followed the NextUI provider setup? https://nextui.org/docs/guide/getting-started#next.js

Comment: Yes but doesnt work ;(

Comment: Hi Luis! Sorry, but in its current state, your question might get downvoted or closed. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking so people can help you better.